# What is the difference between "git push" and "git push origin master"?

Tags: git, github, git-push

After a `git commit`, I have two options:

1. `git push`
2. `git push origin master`

My intent is to push my changes in my local repo to GitHub master branch. In what circumstances do they make a difference?

(Also, what does "origin" here mean?)

---

[UPDATE]:

I think this is not a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462481/what-is-the-difference-between-git-push-origin-and-git-push-origin-master) with this post, because, on the mentioned duplicate post, the question about `git push origin` and in this question is about `git push` only.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`git push` assumes that you already have a [remote repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) defined for that branch.  In this case, the default remote `origin` is used.

`git push origin master` indicates that you are pushing to a *specific* remote, in this case, `origin`.

This would only matter if you created multiple remote repositories in your code base.  If you're only committing to one remote repository (in this case, *just* your GitHub repository), then there isn't any difference between the two.

Comment: In addition, doesn't `git push` push all branches, while `git push origin master` only push the master branch?

Comment: @OliverAngelil When you issue the `git push` command, you are doing so from a specific local branch e.g. `master`. So you will be pushing updates in that local branch to the remote repo. I don't think updates from another local branch will be pushed also, In my opinion.