# Difference between git push and git push origin master

Tags: git, repository, push, branch, gitlab

I want to know that if I only use git command :

```
git push
```

and if I use

```
git push origin master
```

then, what is the difference between them?

I am working on gitlab and i have developer access to the project I am working on.
I am using windows command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push vs git push origin <branchname>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312622/git-push-vs-git-push-origin-branchname)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between git push origin and git push origin master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462481/what-is-the-difference-between-git-push-origin-and-git-push-origin-master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> git push: works like git push "remote", where "remote" is the current
>   branch’s remote (or origin, if no remote is configured for the current
>   branch).

and

> git push origin master: Find a ref that matches master in the source
>   repository (most likely, it would find refs/heads/master), and update
>   the same ref (e.g. refs/heads/master) in origin repository with it. If
>   master did not exist remotely, it would be created.

Please refer this for more information: [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push-codegitpushcode)