# What are the differences of these git push commands?

Tags: git

I recently used this command

```
 git push
```

I want to know what are the differences when I use these commands

```
git push origin master
git push -u
git push -f
```

Comment: So read the docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: `git push --help` and read

Comment: Sadly you're gonna get downvoted because you're straight up asking a question that can be answered by reading the docs. If you're still not sure provide an example poiting out what's not clear so people can help you.

Comment: because i'm new to open source and git i couldn't understand clearly some terms and commands by reading docs that's way i asked here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462481/what-is-the-difference-between-git-push-origin-and-git-push-origin-master

Comment: As Roman Mars says “always read the plaque”. I personally go man page -> tldr (npm tool) -> googling tutorials -> stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**git push** assumes that you already have a remote repository defined for that branch. In this case, the default remote origin is used. **git push origin master** indicates that you are pushing to a specific remote, in this case, origin . This would only matter if you created multiple remote repositories in your code base.

Answer (score 3):

The git push command allows you to send (or push) the commits from your local branch in your local Git repository to the remote repository.[enter link description here](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/git/git-push/)

The most common use of git push is to push your local changes to your public upstream repository. Assuming that the upstream is a remote named “origin” (the default remote name if your repository is a clone) and the branch to be updated to/from is named “master” (the default branch name), this is done with:

git push origin master

[enter link description here](http://reinh.com/blog/2008/04/18/git-push-just-the-tip.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
git push origin master
```

> Find a ref that matches master in the source repository (most likely,
> it would find refs/heads/master), and update the same ref (e.g.
> refs/heads/master) in origin repository with it. If master did not
> exist remotely, it would be created.
>
> -u
> --set-upstream For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less
> git-pull and other commands. For more information, see
> branch..merge in git-config.
>
> -f
> --force Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. Also, when
> --force-with-lease option is used, the command refuses to update a remote ref whose current value does not match what is

[Link to documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)