# in case of working within a branch, why does git push need additional arguments?

Tags: git

I did

```
git checkout -b NEW_BRANCH
```

Everywhere it is being mentioned, that in order to push this to the remote, one has either to tell the push command some additional information

```
git push origin NEW_BRANCH
```

, or one has to associate the local branch with a remote branch

```
git branch --set-upstream origin NEW_BRANCH
```

I don't understand the need for either. In other words, I don't understand the effects of the additional commands? What are they? Or what would happen, if one just says

git push

?
In either of the above commands, does NEW_BRANCH refer to the local branch name or to the remote branch name (if there is a difference)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to do \`--set-upstream\` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1079354

Comment: @Makoto -- the question you mentioned is regarding git pull

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between git push origin and git push origin master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462481/what-is-the-difference-between-git-push-origin-and-git-push-origin-master)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not associated your local branch with a remote branch yet.

Note that branch naming on the remote and local side do not need to be 1-on-1 the same.

In your local state, your branches are "linked" to upstream branches. It just needs to "make that link".

To see the state of which branch is "linked" (tracking) which remote branch, you can use (in case your remote is called `origin`):

```
git remote show origin
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand the need for either. In other words, I don't
>   understand the effects of the additional commands? What are they?

I assume you're talking about this command: `git push <remote-name> <branch-name>`. You also can just do `git push`.

git is a distributed version control system. As such, you may have more than one remote (or even zero remotes). Colloquially, `origin` is the name that's given to the remote after you clone (you can rename it, or remove it, doesn't matter). Hopefully that convinces you why you (might) need to specify the remote. If you have 7 remotes, git can't know which one you want to push to. `origin` is the default remote if you just do `git push`.

git also doesn't know which branch you want to push. You can have many branches. So, it's logical you might want to push some and not others, hence the reason for the `<branch-name>` argument (technically a `refspec`, which is a superset of branches). As a shortcut, you can specify `HEAD` as the commit you want to push (`HEAD` is a pointer to the current commit). So, you can say `git push origin HEAD`, which is especially convenient if you have a long branch name. Again, `git push` will push the current branch by default assuming it has a matching upstream branch. If not, you have to either push it by hand (`git push origin HEAD`) which will create the upstream branch, and then barebones `git push` will work henceforth for that branch, or you can also manually set it as an upstream branch `--set-upstream`.

[Mandatory docs link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple parts to the right answer, which is why this is so confusing.  To understand this properly, let's start by defining some terms:

- A *remote* is a simple name, like `origin` or `upstream`.  This name lets Git store a URL—technically, one or more URLs, but usually just one—so that instead of typing out `https://user@host.dom.ain/some/fairly/long/path/to/some/other/repo.git` or similar, you can just type `origin`.

  Git has one built in, more or less standard, remote named `origin`, which is created by `git clone` and automatically remembers the URL you used when you ran `git clone`.
- A *reference* or *ref* is something you use to refer to commits, such as a branch name or tag name like `master` or `develop`.  References have long forms: `master` is really `refs/heads/master`, for instance.  Most of the time you can just use the short form and not worry about this, but the long form is there, and is what Git uses internally, for handling tricky cases like if you accidentally make a *tag* `master`.  (Don't do that on purpose, but if you do it by mistake, the long form will always let you fix things.)
- A *refspec* is, essentially, a pair of references separated by a colon `:` character.  For instance, `master:master` is a refspec, as is `refs/heads/develop:refs/heads/develop`.  But that's a more complicated form of refspec: you can drop the colon and second name, in a lot of cases, in which case it *looks* like a reference.

What `git push` needs is, in order, one *remote* followed by one or more *refspecs*.

This in turn means the answer to your question:

> ```
> git push origin NEW_BRANCH
> ```
>
> ... does NEW_BRANCH refer to the local branch name or to the remote branch name (if there is a difference)?

is actually a bit more complicated, because that `NEW_BRANCH` isn't a *branch* name after all, it's a *refspec*.  It just *looks like* a branch name!

What `git push` does is to call up another Git.  The other Git "lives" (or at least answers the Internet-phone-call your Git makes) at the URL, which your Git finds by looking up the remote.  Then the two Gits have a conversation, in which your Git finds out what commits their Git has, offers their Git *new* commits if needed, and finally, asks *their* Git to set some of *their* branch names to remember some commits found in *your* Git repository.  (By this point, they have those commits as well, if they didn't before, thanks to the in-between conversation.)

So the `NEW_BRANCH` *refspec* that you give here is actually *both* names.  When you use the form that has the colon in it, you can use two different names, or even use a raw hash ID on your side:

```
git push origin master:somebranch
```

which has your Git offer your new commits and then set *their* `somebranch` to point to the *same* commit that your `master` points to, or:

```
git push origin a123456:refs/heads/somebranch
```

which has your Git make sure they have commit `a123456...` and then set *their* `somebranch` to point to that particular commit.<sup>1</sup>

> I don't understand the need for [remote and refspec]

Well, in fact, often you *don't* need them.  You might think that this would mean *always*, but it doesn't, for multiple historical reasons.

First, Git didn't always have *remotes* at all, so in place of the remote name, you can just write out a URL.<sup>2</sup>  If you don't use either a remote or a URL, Git will figure out a default (often `origin`).  But if you need to list a refspec, you *must* provide either a remote or a URL, because the remote-or-URL has to go in that position in the arguments.

Second, Git *used* to default to pushing multiple branches at once using a rather overly enthusiastic default refspec.  Today, it defaults to pushing one branch using a sane refspec.  This ought to—and does!—make it not need the refspec, but only once some condition is met.  And, you can *change* this default, using `push.default`; if you do, that changes the conditions under which you can omit the refspec(s), and hence the remote name.

Using today's default `push.default` of `simple`, Git will automatically figure out and use the correct remote and refspec *if:*

1. The current branch has an *upstream* set, and
2. The upstream names a branch of the *same* name on the remote.

The remote here can be any of your remotes: if branch `xyz` has an upstream of `foo/xyz`, the remote is `foo` and the branch on `foo` is `xyz` so conditions 1 and 2 are both met and `git push` will do the right thing.

When you first create a new branch, its upstream setting—if any—is determined by *how* you create that branch.  Using `git checkout -b name` gives you a new branch *`name`* that has *no* upstream by default.  Using `git checkout --track remote/name` gives you a new branch *`name`* that has *`remote/name`* as its upstream, and there are various other options that do set some upstream.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you use this form, you usually have to spell out the full reference name.  The reason is that when you use the shortened names, like `git push origin x234`, Git scans through your references to *figure out* whether, say, `x234` is a *branch* name or a *tag* name.  That lets your Git tell their Git: *set your refs/heads/x234* (branch) or *set your refs/tags/x234* (tag).

<sup>2</sup>In those really old versions of Git, you *always* had to supply a URL.  As you might imagine, this was kind of painful.  That led to several experiments, which ultimately produced the idea of a *remote*, and once there was a *standard* remote named `origin`, that allowed you to omit the remote entirely, as long as you could also omit all the refspecs.

The experiments are all still supported as well.  You can use `work:foo` plus an `insteadOf` entry to map `work:` to a host name and optional path therein.